# css, I cannot set font like another site in Safari (mac)

Tags: css, fonts, safari

Ok so I have built this site: http://boardersforchrist.com/new/ and the owner wanted the footer text(font) to be the same as the footer text on http://desiringgod.com.  The font in the lists on desiringgod looks thin compared to boardersforchrist.com/new/

This problem only appears to happen in Safari on a mac.  I have used Web Inspect and cannot see a difference.  Can anyone take 5 and see where my issue is?  This is rediculous... I have been at it for days.  The original html and css came from a theme and the theme is probably got something affecting it...

thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the bfc website, headings such as "Twitter" aren't really headings (`<h2>` elements) at all, but rather a `<li class="footer_page_title">`, which is styled with `font-weight: normal;` instead of `bold`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I know that the headings like Twitter are not an <h#> tag.  The part that is different from the other site is the list items.  like the twitter username, or the purpose, skate demos, staff items in the first column.  If you look at these compared to the other site, the other site font for list item looks alot thinner.